# Make an item wider in menu

Tags: html, css, menu

This is my current menu below.

menu -

```
<ul id="menu"> <li class="one"><a href="http://www.domain.com">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><img src="images/menu-divide.png"></li>
<li class="two"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>">Profile</a></li>
<li><img src="images/menu-divide.png"></li>
<li><?php bp_adminbar_notifications_menu() ?></li>  
<li><img src="images/menu-divide.png"></li>
<li class="three"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>messages">Messages</a>
<li><img src="images/menu-divide.png"></li> 
<li class="five"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>friends">Friends</a></li></ul>
```

This is the css -

```
ul#menu li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0px 0 0;
}

li.one a{
    border-top-left-radius: 3px 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px 3px;
    border-right:none;
width:88px;
}
li.two a, li.three a {
}
li.five a{
    border-top-right-radius: 3px 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px 3px;
    border-left:none;
}

ul#menu li a:link, ul#menu li a:visited {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 88px;
    height: 53px;
    line-height: 53px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #05687b;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;

}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #EDF7FA;
    color: #05687B;

}
```

---

How do I make the first item in the menu wider, say 95px, I can't change one menu item because it changes it all. please help me if you can.

I can't write anymore about this but stackoverflow says I have to, great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add these lines to your code

```
#menu li:first-child {
    width: 95px;
}
```

OR

because you got a class "one" atached to your first "li" element, you could go with

```
#menu li.one{width:95px;}
```

here is a fiddle with width set to 150px on first child and 30px on second element so it was easier to notice the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/mymlyn/8sFSZ/1/

this is how this works: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: i think you might have a bigger problem with your code, are you dividing your menu items using an image? You could just set background to a specific color, and them use padding/margin in order to get the effects you need.

Comment: Solution was not to expand the li size but the a inside of it haha

Comment: still, you should not divide your menu using images:)

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, by referencing the `<a>` node inside of the list item with the class `.one` we can change the width of the whole item regardless of any other rules assigned to that `<a>`.

Solution:

```
  #menu li.one a{
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rzdjd/)

**References:**

[!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules)

**Note:**

Although the !important was not necessary as adding the same css without it to the end of the code would work just aswell, I felt as this avoid further issues in solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's just a small correction you need with the css:

```
li.one a {
    border-top-left-radius: 3px 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px 3px;
    border-right:none; padding:0px 100px 0px 100px;
    width:88px;
}
```